# XCode keeps reverting a deleted line

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have a dependent project (MyLib) inside my main project (MainApp). When I build the MainApp,  XCode gives me an error in one of the .h file of MyLib:

```
#import <MyLib/CvVideoCamera2.h>
```

The error message is:

```
'MyLib/CvVideoCamera2.h' file not found
```

If I delete the import statement, and I clean/build the project, XCode reverts the deleted line and shows the same error!

Any ideas why this line always comes back?

I am running XCode 4.6.2.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing a file that's in your source code directory and not the one that XCode uses inside the `DerivedData` directory?

Comment: I am not sure. I have run XCode as usual. How can I check?

Comment: Select the file from XCode (using the file navigator on the left), then edit it. Check the top bar to verify the file is inside your project directory. Sometimes when you open a file using Cmd-Shift-O you may find yourself editing an incorrect copy of it.

Comment: Also go to your source file via Finder and try to open it from there using any other text editor to verify that your changes were indeed saved to the file (before compilation).

Comment: The file is saved before the compilation but is reverted when I compile. I am also getting sometimes "The document ... could not be saved. The file has been changed by another application".

Comment: Unless you have a custom build script that overrides your changes every time, it's probably a different program that keeps changing your file.

Comment: Is the file open in another program or write protected?

Comment: The file you're editing is probably the header that the build of MyLib puts in `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include` (or wherever) and not the header file in your actual project.  That would explain why it would be "reverted" by each build.